# Image based adsense site

Tags: google-adsense

I got rejected when trying to apply for an adsense account, it said that I'm lacking textual content. Well, that's a real problem. My newly finished site is a image based site with little or no textual content. Even I used Facebook's comment API for the commenting system, which later renders to be an iframe. So it won't even get past the adsense crawler. Users (including me) have uploaded 27 images to the site so far, but I don't think that 1000 images will make any difference. I'm deeply perplexed now and have no idea on how to get my account approved. Any good idea so that I can get my account approved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have many options here; they've already told you exactly what you need to do: find a way to include more text-based content, or move along to another advertising system that works differently.

As you describe things, your site is just fundamentally incompatible with the entire operation of AdSense. It crawls your site's (textual) content to figure out what ads to serve there. If you don't have any, then it [can't really work properly](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81554).

For whatever it's worth, here's a [AdSense forum thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/lsHyLPGHtwU) with someone asking a site that apparently got through somehow, though also note the comment about non-standard code.

Comment: Any good ad company recommendation for my site?

Comment: Try a company like http://www.tradedoubler.com/ which can provide advertising in a non-contextual basis.

Comment: You could also add a blog to the site to build your text-based content.

Comment: @VincePettit Unfortunately tradedoubler is only for europe haha

Comment: You could add something like captions for the photo's. A small description of the picture. Add a part of it as alt, add a caption over the image and you've got yourself some simple text :)